# Create a center menu with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to create a central menu with HTML and CSS, I created the menu but now I can't understand how to put the menu in the center of the page.

I tried to modify the topnav class with margin: auto but nothing happened.

This is my code:

HTML

```
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction(`enter code here`)">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
```

JS

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}`enter code here`
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you would like the text to be centered horizontally.

To do that, you just need to add text-align:center; to topnav.

The property that you used, margin: auto; would center the navigation bar itself (and not its content), but has no consequence since it already occupies the entire width of the screen.

```
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aud5bsq4/7/

Answer (score 1):

Using a flexbox for `.topnav` makes it simple to center the menu.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction(`enter code here`)">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center the entire `.topnav` bar, you will have to give it a width. Otherwise it will always be as wide as 100% of it's parent element (in this case I'm assuming that's the Body).

Try adding:

```
.topnav {
    width: "your width here";
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Here's an example of what that would look like with 300px width.

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction(`enter code here`)">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
```

If you are simply trying to center the elements within your `.topnav` you can try [turning it into a Flexbox element](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Try adding:

```
.topnav {
     display:flex;
     justify-content: center;
}
```

Here's an example of using flexbox to center your menu's elements:

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction(`enter code here`)">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
```